# Rota post ajax Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, algoritmo-de-busca

Galera tenho um campo de busca por ajax no laravel que funciona normalmente local mas no servidor ele está retornando erro. Quando a rota de busca 
(post -> http://site.com.br/cidadedigital/admin/prefeitura/search/) é disparada  pelo evento keyup da o erro 301 Moved Permanently e em seguida executa novamente (misteriosamente) uma outra rota (get -> http://site.com.br/prefeitura/search/) que consequentemente retorna erro 404 not found porque essa segunda rota realmente não existe.

Esse erro só ocorre através do ajax, quando eu dou enter e o formulário é enviado de forma convencional a rota é encontrada e os resultado são exibidos corretamente.

Alguém já teve problemas desse tipo? Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é problema nos códigos ou alguma configuração do servidor?

Essa é a rota que está no routes.php

```
Route::post('/prefeitura/search', 'Admin\PrefeituraController@search');
```

Esse é o .htaccess que está na pasta root do laravel (arquivos da pasta public também foram movidas para a pasta root do laravel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Esta é a função ajax que faz a busca e exibe os dados encontrados

```
$("#searchPrefeitura").on('keyup',function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://site.com.br/cidadedigital/admin/prefeitura/search/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType    : 'html',
        encode      : true,
        data        :{exp:$(this).val(), _token: $("#_tokenSearch").val()},
        beforeSend  : function(){
            $(".spinner").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success     : function(data){
            $("#listPrefeitura").html(data);
        },
        complete    : function(){       
            $(".spinner").addClass('hide');
            $("#limpabusca").fadeIn();
        },

        error   :   function(data)
        {
            //console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Tenta chamar no ajax só a url da rota msm da forma que ta registrada, não da certo? /prefeitura/search

Comment: Nesse caso ele da somente o erro Not Found mas ainda assim não funcionou.
The requested URL /prefeitura/search was not found on this server.

Comment: ue, mas como pode dar o 404 se a rota ta registrada assim... quando vc da o enter ele funciona indo pra q rota? a /cidadedigital/admin/prefeitura/search ?

Comment: vc colocou assim msm? url: '/prefeitura/search',

Comment: Exatamente assim. Tentei com barra no final também, e deu o mesmo resultado. Também não entendo como pode estar dando erro se a rota está correta.

Comment: é cara, não sei msm... o url: '/cidadedigital/admin/prefeitura/search', tbm n funcionou?

Comment: se recebesse um 302 iria perguntar se seria talvez uma questão de permissão da rota, mas o 301...

Comment: Cara valeu pela ajuda. Agora eu consegui resolver aqui. Tive que deixar a url no ajax dessa forma /cidadedigital/admin/prefeitura/search e no arquivo de rotas dessa forma /prefeitura/search.
Achei um comportamento bem estranho não funcionar com a barra (/) no final das rotas. Mas era esse o problema, sem barra no final funciona e com a barra não funciona.

Comment: Mistérios rs, mas que bom que conseguiu @user5103